# Uploading a video on youtube gives error ios

Tags: ios, video, youtube-api, gdata

I am using this code to upload videos to Youtube through my application - [Uploading Videos on youtube](http://urinieto.com/2010/10/upload-videos-to-youtube-with-iphone-custom-app/) . Now the thing is, the video is never being uploaded and I am wlways getting this error :

```
serviceBase:<GDataServiceGoogleYouTube: 0x155e3710> objectFetcher:<GDataHTTPUploadFetcher: 0x15662c10> failedWithStatus:400 data:<errors xmlns='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'><error><domain>GData</domain><code>InvalidRequestUriException</code><internalReason>Exception message unavailable</internalReason></error></errors>
```

No matter what I do. My upload code for Youtube is as below :

```
- (void)uploadPressed{
NSString *devKey = @"some key";

GDataServiceGoogleYouTube *service = [self youTubeService];
[service setYouTubeDeveloperKey:devKey];

NSString *kGDataServiceDefaultUser = @"isome@gmail.com";
NSString *clientID = @"googleusercontent.com";

NSURL *url = [GDataServiceGoogleYouTube youTubeUploadURLForUserID:kGDataServiceDefaultUser
                                                         clientID:clientID];

// load the file data



NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"vid1.mp4"];
NSData *myData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:appFile] ;

// gather all the metadata needed for the mediaGroup
NSString *titleStr = @"Survey App";
GDataMediaTitle *title = [GDataMediaTitle textConstructWithString:titleStr];

NSString *categoryStr = @"Comedy";
GDataMediaCategory *category = [GDataMediaCategory mediaCategoryWithString:categoryStr];
[category setScheme:kGDataSchemeYouTubeCategory];

NSString *descStr = @"Survey Description.";
GDataMediaDescription *desc = [GDataMediaDescription textConstructWithString:descStr];

NSString *keywordsStr = @"survey";
GDataMediaKeywords *keywords = [GDataMediaKeywords keywordsWithString:keywordsStr];

BOOL isPrivate = YES;

GDataYouTubeMediaGroup *mediaGroup = [GDataYouTubeMediaGroup mediaGroup];
[mediaGroup setMediaTitle:title];
[mediaGroup setMediaDescription:desc];
[mediaGroup addMediaCategory:category];
[mediaGroup setMediaKeywords:keywords];
[mediaGroup setIsPrivate:isPrivate];

NSString *mimeType = [GDataUtilities MIMETypeForFileAtPath:documentsDirectory
                                           defaultMIMEType:@"video/mp4"];

// create the upload entry with the mediaGroup and the file data
GDataEntryYouTubeUpload *entry;
entry = [GDataEntryYouTubeUpload uploadEntryWithMediaGroup:mediaGroup
                                                      data:myData
                                                  MIMEType:mimeType
                                                      slug:@"vid1.mp4"];

SEL progressSel = @selector(ticket:hasDeliveredByteCount:ofTotalByteCount:);
[service setServiceUploadProgressSelector:progressSel];

GDataServiceTicket *ticket;
ticket = [service fetchEntryByInsertingEntry:entry
                                  forFeedURL:url
                                    delegate:self
                           didFinishSelector:@selector(uploadTicket:finishedWithEntry:error:)];

[self setUploadTicket:ticket];

}

#pragma mark -

- (GDataServiceGoogleYouTube *)youTubeService {

static GDataServiceGoogleYouTube* service = nil;

if (!service) {
    service = [[GDataServiceGoogleYouTube alloc] init];

    [service setShouldCacheDatedData:YES];
    [service setServiceShouldFollowNextLinks:YES];
    [service setIsServiceRetryEnabled:YES];
}

// update the username/password each time the service is requested
NSString *kGDataServiceDefaultUser = @"isome@gmail.com";
NSString *password = @"passwrd";

[GDataHTTPFetcher setIsLoggingEnabled:YES];

if ([kGDataServiceDefaultUser length] > 0 && [password length] > 0) {
    [service setUserCredentialsWithUsername:kGDataServiceDefaultUser
                                   password:password];
} else {
    // fetch unauthenticated
    [service setUserCredentialsWithUsername:nil
                                   password:nil];
}

NSString *devKey = @"some key";
[service setYouTubeDeveloperKey:devKey];

return service;
}

// progress callback
- (void)ticket:(GDataServiceTicket *)ticket
hasDeliveredByteCount:(unsigned long long)numberOfBytesRead
ofTotalByteCount:(unsigned long long)dataLength {

//    [mProgressView setProgress:(double)numberOfBytesRead / (double)dataLength];
}

// upload callback
- (void)uploadTicket:(GDataServiceTicket *)ticket
   finishedWithEntry:(GDataEntryYouTubeVideo *)videoEntry
           error:(NSError *)error {
if (error == nil) {
    // tell the user that the add worked
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Uploaded!"
                                                    message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@    succesfully uploaded",
                                                             [[videoEntry title] stringValue]]
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show];
} else {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!"
                                                    message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error: %@",
                                                             [error description]]
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show];
}
//    [mProgressView setProgress: 0.0];

[self setUploadTicket:nil]
```